# How do I capture multiple groups after an initial string match using a regex?

Tags: .net, regex, regex-group

Test data:

`TESTING: FIRST SECOND THIRD
TESTING:
TESTING: ANY NUMBER OF WHOLE WORDS
flibble:`

...should give the following:

- List: [FIRST,SECOND,THIRD]
- List: Empty
- List: [ANY,NUMBER,OF,WHOLE,WORDS]
- No match

I thought something like this might work:

`TESTING:(\s(\w+))*`

...but I'm unsure how to make those extra words capture repeatedly. My attempt above [doesn't seem to work](https://regex101.com/r/0rekTx/1).

Comment: What language? Check out this https://regex101.com/r/obyKdV/1

Comment: .net (C# or C++-cli)

Comment: If in .NET, your regex already works. Access capture collection items. See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=ALARMS%3a%28%5cs%28%5cw%2b%29%29*&i=ALARMS%3a+FIRST+SECOND+).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I think that example suggests (looking at the split list) that it captured the 'SECOND' string twice?

Comment: @JonCage Table > $2 > 2 captures

Comment: Maybe I've missed something but the duplicate you've suggested doesn't appear to deal with having a bit up front that needs matching.